# IOS Web UI View

Tags: user-interface, web, xamarin.ios

I have wrapped up a web application in webuiview for IOS. In the application, I have a scenario where you can tap on a button and an auto-generated PDF file is loaded. The trouble is when you close that PDF file, the user is logged off of the app.

Any thoughts on this?

Thanks

Comment: How do you load the PDF?  Is it loaded in-app, or in an external viewer?  How do you close it?  There is very little useful context in your question.

Comment: Thank you. The PDF is opened in a separate browser window when the app is run in the browser. We did not change anything; just wrap the web app up and deploy it to the Apple Store.

Comment: if a separate app is launched to view the PDF, it is normal iOS behavior to NOT return to the calling app when the new app is closed

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: @mapussah Hi, if you have solved it, you could update it as an answer.